UIViewRepresentable react to changes in view frame
I have a UIView that draws some things on a CALayer using paths. For the correct size of the drawing it depends on the view's frame.
Now I'm trying to use this view in SwiftUI and for this I'm using UIViewRepresentable. My first problem was that I could not get the correct frame for the view however I worked around this by wrapping my representable view in a GeometryReader which in imo is not the best but it works. Now the problem is that when my view changes its size (for example the screen is rotated) I don't know how to receive a notification so I can update my drawing.
As far as I understand, the updateUIView(_:) method is not called unless some state of the view hierarchy changes and it doesn't seem to be called on rotation.
struct MyRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    var geometry: GeometryProxy

    func makeUIView(_ view: UIView, context: Context) -> UIView {
         let view = UIView()
         let size = geometry.size
         view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
         context.coordinator.view = view
         context.coordinator.draw()
         return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: UIView, context: Context) {
         let size = geometry.size
         context.coordinator.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
         context.coordinator.update()
    }
}

Edit:
The draw method looks something like this:
// locations is [CLLocation]
let points = locations.map { $0.cgPoint }
let path = CGMutablePath()
    
path.move(to: points[0])
for index in 1..<points.count {
   path.addLine(to: points[index])
}
    
var transform = getTransformation(for: path)
let transformedPath = path.copy(using: &transform)
    
let newLayer = CAShapeLayer()
newLayer.path = transformedPath
newLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
newLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
newLayer.lineWidth = 6

self.view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)


Please show a [mcve] of how you "could not get the correct frame for the view" (i.e. the first version of your code that didn't use GeometryReader). It sounds like you should create a UIView subclass and do the drawing in its draw method. If you then set contentMode to .redraw, it will be redrawn whenever the frame changes.

The updateUIView is called once when the view is first shown, if I add a breakpoint there and check the views frame or bounds, they are all 0. I can try creating a uiview subclass

I'm "drawing" using CGPath and CALayer. Coded is added to the question. I'm not drawing in the update, I'm just trying to update get the view frame somewhere

And to provide some context, my base case is drawing some paths on a map, and this view is only used when google maps is not available (china)

Okay so you are adding a CAShapeLayer as a sublayer. That will easily break when updateUIView is called multiple times. The drawing code seems like it can totally be done in a UIView subclass' draw method, or just a SwiftUI Canvas. Why do you need a UIViewRepresentable?

The map component is not only used in SwiftUI but older, UIKit based screens as well. I will try creating a custom UIView and draw like that

That doesn't make sense. In your UIViewRepresentable, you are returning a plain UIView from makeUIView, not some reusable "map component". Do you mean in your real code you are actually returning some other type of view? If so, you should create a subclass of that type and override draw.

When I said the component is used in other places, probably I should have used future tense. Eventually I would have created a UIView subclass but wanted to figure out drawing before

Okay, so you are going to need to create a UIView subclass anyway. Better to do it now then! :-)

Yeah, with draw it is much easier. I can accept it as an answer if you want to add it

I like using a UIViewController, then you can use constraints to pin the UIView to the edges

I would create a custom UIView and do the drawing in its draw method.
class MyView: UIView {
    var locations: [CLLocation] = []

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // put your drawing logic here...
        // you can access self.bounds here!

        let points = locations.map { $0.cgPoint }
        let path = CGMutablePath()
            
        path.move(to: points[0])
        for index in 1..<points.count {
           path.addLine(to: points[index])
        }
            
        var transform = getTransformation(for: path)
        let transformedPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: path.copy(using: &transform))
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        transformedPath.lineWidth = 6
        transformedPath.stroke()
    }
}

struct MyRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(_ view: MyView, context: Context) -> MyView {
         let view = MyView()
         // this is so that 'draw' is called every time the frame of the view changes
         view.contentMode = .redraw

         return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MyView, context: Context) {
         view.locations = someUpdatedLocations
    }
}


Also consider using a SwiftUI Canvas to do the drawing. The size of the Canvas is given as one of its closure parameters, and you can port it to UIKit using a UIHostingController.
struct MyView: View {
    let locations: [CLLocation]
    
    var body: some View {
        Canvas { gc, size in
            // use 'size' here to do your drawing
        }
    }
}

